# React.js - How do I pass data from a div to a function with axios POST method?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I want to pass strings from a mapped element to a function that is supposed to trigger on click of said element to then do the post request. This is the function:

```
const update = () => {
    axios.
      post("http://localhost:4000/api/albums/favorites", "???")
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
      })
  }
```

And this is where my mapped data is:

```
return(
    <Container className="d-flex flex-column py-2" style={{ height: "100vh" }}>
      <Form.Control
        type="search"
        placeholder="Search Songs/Artists"
        value={search}
        onChange={e => setSearch(e.target.value)}
      />
      <div className="flex-grow-1 my-100" style={{ overflowY: "auto" }}>
        <div className="d-flex m-2 align-items-center card-body">  
          {searchResult.map(result => (
            <div style={{ cursor: "pointer" }} onClick={update}> 
              <img key={result.imageUrl} src={result.imageUrl} alt=""/>
              {result.artistName} - {result.albumName}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </Container>
  );
```

This is data I got from results of a search bar through api. How should I refer the data in place of ??? in the update function? I tried looking for an answer but I probably don't know how to articulate my problem very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass each result to your `update` function like this

```
<div style={{ cursor: "pointer" }} onClick={() => update(result)}> 
...
```

and make your update function to accept an argument that you would use in your axios request

```
const update = (data) => {
    axios.
      post("http://localhost:4000/api/albums/favorites", data)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
      })
}
```

Now each result div when clicked will trigger the update function but bound to its data

Comment: @mehawelm11 please consider marking the answer as accepted (the checkmark under) if it fully answers your question.